# How to print select statment in a plsql script?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have two arrays where I have stored some valid values for a table and I'm passing them in a `SELECT` statement. I'm doing it so that array `a` and `b` values enter where condition at correspondingly.

I am using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to print the `SELECT` statement, I have tried inserting the value of the `SELECT` statement in a variable and printing it via `dbms_output.put_line` but it gave an error.

And my code doesn't print anything, it just shows procedure completed.

```
DECLARE
  dest temp_1.destination%type;
  type arr1 IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(50); 
  sd arr1; 
  type arr2 IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(50); 
  sid1 arr2; 
  total integer;
BEGIN
 sd := street_directional('a','b','c','d');
 sid1 := street_direction('1','2','3','4');
   total := sd.count;
   FOR i in 1 .. total LOOP 
      execute immediate q'[select destination from temp_1 where cond1 =(:var1) and cond2 = (:var2) ]' using sd(i),sid1(i);  

   END LOOP; 
END;
```

This doesn't give any output, it just shows procedure complete.

I tried doing this:

```
execute immediate q'[select destination from temp_1 where cond1 =(:var1) and cond2 = (:var2) into dest]' using sd(i),sid1(i); 
      return dest;
-- or printline
dbms_output.put_line(dest);
```

but it gave an error.
I have kept the `serveroutput on` and im running this on oracle engine.

If there is some easy way of getting the result other than using PL/SQL, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with dynamic SQL you need to select *into* something, which has to be outside the dynamic part of the statement. In fact, with dynamic SQL, if you don't then the query is parsed but not executed. (Other DML and DDL behave differently of course.) Your second block has `into dest` but inside the query string, which isn't doing anything; and you can't return a value from an anonymous block.

```
execute immediate q'[select destination from temp_1 where cond1 =(:var1) and cond2 = (:var2)]'
  into dest
  using sd(i),sid1(i); 

dbms_output.put_line(dest);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6837494a2a7d51d5a7304350cb82a28f)

You still need to have `set serveroutput on` in your client, or equivalent, to see the `dest` output. And if there is no matching row in `temp_1` for any of the pairs of condition values then you'll get a no-data-found exception, so you'll need to decide if that's possible and what you want to do if it happens.

It doesn't look like this really needs to be dynamic - I included a static version in the fiddle using:

```
select destination into dest from temp_1 where cond1 = sd(i) and cond2 = sid1(i);

dbms_output.put_line(dest);
```

... or even really PL/SQL, but presumably is an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using Execute IMMEDIATE? You can print select statement in a plsql as below.

```
    DECLARE
  dest temp_1.destination%type;
  type arr1 IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(50); 
  sd arr1; 
  type arr2 IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(50); 
  sid1 arr2; 
  total integer;
BEGIN
 sd := arr1('a','b','c','d');
 sid1 := arr2('1','2','3','4');
   total := sd.count;
   FOR i in 1 .. total LOOP 
      select destination into dest from temp_1  where cond1 =sd(i) and cond2 = sid1(i) ;
      dbms_output.put_line(dest);  
   END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [dbms_output.enable(null)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67317) like:

```
execute immediate q'[select destination from temp_1 where cond1 =(:var1) and cond2 = (:var2)]'
  into dest
  using sd(i),sid1(i); 

dbms_output.enable(null);
dbms_output.put_line(dest);
```

or enable [spooling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/maxl_commands_spool.html) to a file.

```
spool on to 'output.txt';
execute immediate q'[select destination from temp_1 where cond1 =(:var1) and cond2 = (:var2)]'
  into dest
  using sd(i),sid1(i); 

spool off;
```

Check also [ask tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1968769482859)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer as all the details are behind links to other sites (and in another castle). It would be better if the relevant sections were included  and an example given how to apply it to the OP's situation.

Comment: Your spool doc link is to a different Oracle product, not the database. Spool is [a client command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SPOOL.html) and doesn't have quite that syntax; and can't be within a PL/SQL block. The client would have to turn spooling on, then execute the block - and the block would still have to use `dbms_output`. So spool is a bit of a red-herring here I think.